# How can I put PayPal discount codes on my checkout

Tags: javascript, html

Just doing a simple code to apply promo code on my PayPal button. I just did like below but the validate() function did not alert.

I hope all codes are correct. Please check the Fiddle and do let me know why the functions are not working.

```js
function validate( text1, text2 ) {

   if ( text1 == text2 ) {
    window.alert( "Nice, you get a 10% Discount!" );
   }
   if ( text1 !== text2 ) {
    window.alert( "Sorry, No Discount!" );
   }
  }

  function CalculateOrder( form ) {

   if ( form.text1.value == "GOLD10" ) {
    form.discount_rate.value = "10";
    form.discount_rate2.value = "10";
    form.on3.value = "Coupon Entered";
    form.os3.value = "GOLD10";
   }
  }
```

```html
<form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="fanciedmedia@gmail.com"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Blue Kidsport Burst"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="149.00"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="weight_unit" value="lbs">
  <input type="hidden" name="baseamt" value="149.00"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="BUONBL">
  <span id="dist"></span>

  <input type="text" name="text1">
  <input type="button" value="Check It" name="Submit" onclick=javascript&colon;validate(text1.value, "GOLD10")>
  <br>
  <input name="submit" type="image" alt="Add to Cart" src="add_to.png" onclick=CalculateOrder(this.form)/>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed adding simple quotes `'` in the `onclick` attributes, and you should refer to form object in order to get `text1` value:

```
onclick=javascript&colon;validate(text1.value, "GOLD10")
        ^^                        ^^^                   ^^

onclick=CalculateOrder(this.form)
        ^^                       ^^
```

It should be:

```
onclick='javascript&colon;validate(form.text1.value, "GOLD10")'
onclick='CalculateOrder(this.form)'
```

Try this code:

```js
function validate( text1, text2 ) {

  if ( text1 == text2 ) {
    window.alert( "Nice, you get a 10% Discount!" );
  }
  if ( text1 !== text2 ) {
    window.alert( "Sorry, No Discount!" );
  }
}

function CalculateOrder( form ) {

  if ( form.text1.value == "GOLD10" ) {
    form.discount_rate.value = "10";
    form.discount_rate2.value = "10";
    form.on3.value = "Coupon Entered";
    form.os3.value = "GOLD10";
  }
  
  alert('submitting form');
  form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="fanciedmedia@gmail.com"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Blue Kidsport Burst"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="149.00"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="weight_unit" value="lbs">
  <input type="hidden" name="baseamt" value="149.00"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="BUONBL">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="discount_rate" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="discount_rate2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="on3" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="os3" value="">
  <span id="dist"></span>

  <input type="text" name="text1">
  <input type="button" value="Check It" name="Submit" onclick='javascript&colon;validate(form.text1.value, "GOLD10")'>
  <br>
  <input type="button" alt="Add to Cart" src="add_to.png" value="add to cart" onclick='CalculateOrder(form)'/>

 </form>
```

Comment: That's because you are trying to set values to an undefined inputs, you have to create `discount_rate` `discount_rate2` `on3` `os3` as hidden inputs and update there values in `CalculateOrder` function, I update my answer for you